# NMUUE library for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I' m trying to run a project on Delphi 7 and getting file not found error 'NMUUE.dcu'. It is needed to create TNMUUProcessor object. Reinstalling doesn't help . So where can I find this library for my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've migrated this project from a lower version of Delphi. If I remember correctly, NMUUE is the UUE encoding unit for the Fastnet internet components. These didn't ship with Delphi 7 (I think Delphi 5 was the last version that supported them). I'm not sure if there's a download available for it still as NetMasters have gone out of business. Your best bet would be to migrate the project to use something like Indy.

Comment: Thanks .Yes,the project was written on Delhphi 6.7.

Answer (score 2):

That component is part of FastNet. It is not distributed with Delphi 7: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29766

> The Fastnet components are no longer bundled with Delphi. It appears Netmasters does have a version compatible with Delphi 7 which can be purchased at: http://www.netmastersllc.com/

You probably will need to upgrade to a paid version of FastNet that supports Delphi 7, if such a thing can still be obtained, or switch to Indy.

On the other hand, if you are not actually doing anything more than uuencoding you could easily find a Delphi uuencode function with a websearch.

You probably ought to try to understand your program and what its requirements are before you proceed much further. Blindly solving missing dependencies without understanding why your program needs them is usually a recipe for future pain.

Comment: Yes, I guess its needed only for uuencoding.

Comment: There are only these code lines try
 NMUUProcessor1.InputStream := FS1;
        NMUUProcessor1.OutputStream := FS2;
        NMUUProcessor1.Encode;                                             finally FS1.free; FS2.Free; Where FS1 and FS2 are filestreams How can I rewrite this using Indy in short way(encription cipher is not important)? Or better should I look for uuencode function from inet as you said above. I have seen some similar questions,but didn't like much because solution is a bit long.

Comment: I'd just use a simple uuencode function. Drawing in Indy seems a little over the top. Anyway, why are you asking me this new question in comments to my answer? Perhaps you should ask a new question? Or perhaps you can ask Andy_D!  ;-)

Comment: I'm curious. Why did you add the comments to my answer rather than Andy's?

Comment: Because you wrote "On the other hand, if you are not actually doing anything more than uuencoding you could easily find a Delphi uuencode function with a websearch."  I and wanted to know which way is better? using Indy or uuencode function

Comment: Well, which do you think is better? I'd personally use my own uuencode which is trivial to implement.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think ,I had to learn more about Indy and uuencode before asking question).